# How to get console.log() output from the child process in "execa"?

Tags: node.js, child-process

Below code starts Electron application, however, `console.log()` from the main process will not be available.

```
import executeExternalCommand, { ExecaReturnValue } from 'execa';

async startInitializeProjectGUI(): Promise<void> {

  const executionResult: ExecaReturnValue<string> = await executeExternalCommand(
      'electron',
      ['InitializeProject_GUI.js'], // console.log() is here
      { cwd: __dirname }
  );

  if (executionResult.failed) {
    Promise.reject(new Error('Can not start "electron"'));
  }

  return;
}
```

How can I get console output of child process with [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa)?

Comment: Where are you using `console.log`?

Comment: @JackBashford, In InitializeProject_GUI.ts, which compiled to InitializeProject_GUI.js by Webpack with { target: 'electron-main' } option.