# How to start electron application programically via child_process?

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I need to start the electron.js application programically. Below solution with [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa) library works, however I did not find the answer, how to make console to display `console.log()` inside `InitializeProject_GUI.js` ([here is that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539690/how-to-get-console-log-output-from-the-child-process-in-execa)).

```js
import executeExternalCommand, { ExecaReturnValue } from 'execa';

const executionResult: ExecaReturnValue<string> = await executeExternalCommand(
    'electron',
    ['InitializeProject_GUI.js'],
    { cwd: __dirname }
);
```

So I decided to use standard `child_process` instead. Maybe it will be easier to find how to display `console.log()`'s of child process, but first I need to make electron application start.

```js
import ChildProcess, { ChildProcess as ChildProcess__type } from 'child_process';

const childProcess: ChildProcess__type = ChildProcess.spawn(
    'electron',
    ['InitializeProject_GUI.js'],
    { cwd: __dirname }
);
```

I got `Error: spawn electron ENOENT`:

[image]

Also, `ChildProcess.exec('electron InitializeProject_GUI.js', { cwd: __dirname });` do NOTHING.

And, `ChildProcess.execSync('electron InitializeProject_GUI.js', { cwd: __dirname });` causes the error with broken encoding:

[image]

Comment: Concertized question in [How to execute locally installed Node.js application by child_process.spawn()?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732419/how-to-execute-locally-installed-node-js-application-by-child-process-spawn).